# Getting error when i try to click on the link text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

It is a href I am trying to click on this using the below code however, it is not able to find link text. It has no frames and it is on the same window. Not sure what is going on

```
self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("UNITED WAY OF EASTERN UTAH").click()
```

This is the screenshot of the element code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess here, but has the page fully loaded (including any content created by dynamic code e.g. javascript) before you try to click on the link. If the link is created after you try to find it then obviously it will be missing. Try putting a `time.sleep` before you try to find it.

Took a closer look to the screenshot and this should help. You are using `find_element_by_link_text` which if I am not mistaken looks for a complete match between the provided text and the text in the link. However the text in your link is not an exact match. You should use `find_element_by_partial_link_text` instead

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: ahh not sure why i did not think about that. it seems to work now. thank you so much